# Custom UserControl events

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, mvvm-light

I have an `UserControl` defined as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Speaker.View.Controls.Prompt"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Speaker.View.Converters"
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="Auto" Width="300" x:Name="PromptBox">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <conv:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Border Background="White" Padding="10" BorderThickness="1" 
        BorderBrush="Gray" CornerRadius="10" Height="80" 
        Visibility="{Binding Path=Show, ElementName=PromptBox, 
                             Converter={StaticResource VConverter}}" 
        UseLayoutRounding="True">
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" RenderingBias="Quality" />
    </Border.Effect>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="InputText" Width="Auto" Height="20" 
                 Text="{Binding Path=InfoText, ElementName=PromptBox, Mode=OneWay}"
                 Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="#FF8D8D8D" 
                 GotFocus="InputText_GotFocus" LostFocus="InputText_LostFocus" />
        <Separator Grid.Row="1" />
        <Button Content="{Binding Path=ButtonText, ElementName=PromptBox}" Grid.Row="2" 
                Width="100" Command="{Binding Path=OkCommand, ElementName=PromptBox}" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

What I want to do is this:

when the user clicks on the button, I'd like to run some code (obviously :) ) - this control will be used in some other controls / windows, and the code I'd like to run will be different depending on a scenarion. So how do I bind the `Command` property of this button with some custom command? Example usage:

```
<ctrls:Prompt Show="{Binding ShouldLogIn}" ButtonText="{Binding LogInText}"
              InfoText="{Binding LogInInfo}" OkCommand="what goes here???" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ZIndex="2" />
```

Also - I follow the MVVM patern, using the MVVMLight fw, so I'd like the solution to follow it as well.

So the question is - How do I bind to the Button.Command from outside of the prompt control?

Comment: This seems fine , you do not need to bind any thing from the propmpt 
Bind oneway: Button.Command <- propmpt.OkCommand

Comment: But How do I bind to prompt Button.Command from outside of prompt Control?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf

Comment: I would recommend making a "custom control" instead of using UserControl. IMO it fits better with what you are trying to do. You could inherit from TextBox and add some DependecyProperties for the Command(s) you would like. The XAML you have now, you can basically use as the control template. The other option if you really want to use UserControl is to make an attached DependecyProperty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would also suggest making a CustomControl, but if you want to use your UserControl you will need to add a DependencyProperty in your code behind.

```
public partial class Prompt : UserControl
{
    private bool _canExecute;
    private EventHandler _canExecuteChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// DependencyProperty for the OKCommand property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OKCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("OKCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Prompt), new PropertyMetadata(OnOKCommandChanged));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the command to invoke when the OKButton is pressed.
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand OKCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(OKCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OKCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value that becomes the return value of
    /// System.Windows.UIElement.IsEnabled in derived classes.
    /// </summary>
    protected override bool IsEnabledCore
    {
        get { return base.IsEnabledCore && _canExecute; }
    }

    // Command dependency property change callback. 
    private static void OnOKCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Prompt p = (Prompt)d;
        p.HookUpCommand((ICommand)e.OldValue, (ICommand)e.NewValue);
    }

    public Prompt()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Add the command. 
    private void AddCommand(ICommand command)
    {
        EventHandler handler = new EventHandler(CanExecuteChanged);
        _canExecuteChanged = handler;
        if (command != null)
            command.CanExecuteChanged += _canExecuteChanged;
    }

   private void CanExecuteChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OKCommand != null)
            _canExecute = OKCommand.CanExecute(null);

        CoerceValue(UIElement.IsEnabledProperty);
    }

    // Add a new command to the Command Property. 
    private void HookUpCommand(ICommand oldCommand, ICommand newCommand)
    {
        // If oldCommand is not null, then we need to remove the handlers. 
        if (oldCommand != null)
            RemoveCommand(oldCommand);

        AddCommand(newCommand);
    }

    // Remove an old command from the Command Property. 
    private void RemoveCommand(ICommand command)
    {
        EventHandler handler = CanExecuteChanged;
        command.CanExecuteChanged -= handler;
    }
}
```